# OS X - how to get access to USB printer

Tags: macos, printing, usb, iokit

I try to write application for OS X that will print barcodes on Xprinter xp-370b that connecting with USB.
I use IOKit libraries.

I can get device object of this printer in my code as `io_service_t device;`. Then I create `IOUSBDeviceInterface **dev;` and open device with `(*dev)->USBDeviceOpen(dev);`.

How can I send any message to this device? I try:

```
IOReturn WriteToDeviceZ(IOUSBDeviceInterface **dev, UInt16 length, UInt8 writeBuffer[])
{
    IOUSBDevRequest request;
    IOReturn kr;
    USBDeviceAddress address;
    kr = (*dev)->GetDeviceAddress(dev, &address);
    if (kr != kIOReturnSuccess)
    {
        printf("No address err 0x%x\n", kr);
        return kr;
    }

    request.bmRequestType = USBmakebmRequestType(kUSBOut, kUSBVendor, kUSBDevice);
    request.bRequest = 0xa0;
    request.wValue = address;
    request.wIndex = 0;
    request.wLength = length;
    request.pData = writeBuffer;

    return (*dev)->DeviceRequest(dev, &request);
}
```

But ii returns error

```
kr = WriteToDeviceZ(dev, sizeof(array), array);
if (kr != kIOReturnSuccess)
{
    printf("WriteToDevice reset returned err 0x%x\n", kr);
    (*dev)->USBDeviceClose(dev);
    (*dev)->Release(dev);
    return kr;
}

WriteToDevice reset returned err 0xe000404f
```

Maybe there is another method how can I interact with printer through USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main protocol for most USB devices is typically not implemented via device requests. Instead, each device normally has one or more USB interfaces which each have one or more endpoints. You communicate with those endpoints through pipes. On macOS, you enumerate the device's interfaces with `CreateInterfaceIterator` to obtain `IOUSBInterfaceInterface` handles (or if it's a composite/well-known device type, you can just match the interface directly during IOKit matching), then read/write to the pipes with the `ReadPipe`/`WritePipe` family of functions. (There are variants with Async and/or TO (timeout) suffixes, I most frequently use `ReadPipeAsyncTO`/`WritePipeAsyncTO` as they give you the most control.)

Comment: how can I get `IOUSBInterfaceInterface` from 'IOUSBDeviceInterface'?

Comment: I try this. But iterator don't have any interfaceRefs
`IOUSBFindInterfaceRequest request;
io_iterator_t intIterator;
io_service_t interfaceRef;
    (*dev)->CreateInterfaceIterator(dev, &request, &intIterator);
    while ((interfaceRef = IOIteratorNext(intIterator)) != 0)
    {
}`

Comment: You need to fill out the request struct.

Comment: Setting `request.bInterfaceClass = kIOUSBFindInterfaceDontCare; request.bInterfaceSubClass = kIOUSBFindInterfaceDontCare; request.bInterfaceProtocol = kIOUSBFindInterfaceDontCare; request.bAlternateSetting = kIOUSBFindInterfaceDontCare;` worked for me. Now I have device interface